# How can I make my circle image look like a circle in mobile?

Tags: html, css, image, bootstrap-4

I have circle images in my website, and since I'm using Bootstrap 4, I am using the class `rounded-circle`. This works fine in desktop, but in mobile the circle becomes an oval. (Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/paulamourad/pen/NWjZXLJ))

Desktop looks fine:

[image]

Mobile looks like an oval (iPhone XR):

[image]

My code:

```
<div class="nh-service-card-image-wrapper">
    <img src="images/guitar.jpg" alt="Reebit" class="img-fluid rounded-circle" 
    width="85" height="85">
</div>


 .nh-service-card-image-wrapper {
    aspect-ratio: 1;
 }

 .nh-service-card-img img {
     object-fit: cover;  
     width: 90% !important;
     height: 90% !important;
     margin-top: 1.2em;
 }
```

Note: The `width="85"` and `height="85"` that you see in my `img` tag is required due to the technology I'm using.

Comment: I think it is due to `img-fluid` class which makes the image responsive. If you want fixed image dimensions for all screens, then you can remove this class.

Comment: Safari on IOS does not appear to have yet implemented aspect-ratio.

Comment: I'm working with Chrome right now and even if I remove the class `img-fluid` it still shows like an oval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the class `img-fluid`. That will reset your image's height to auto and width 100%.

Try removing that class then It should work.

Additional: You are using `margin-top: 1.2rem` which will not work unless until you make your image `inline-block` or `block`;

Comment: Ok so I removed the `img-fluid` class but it still renders as an oval.

Comment: Try removing 90% width and height

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by hard coding as you can see your image is oval on width side so you must reduce `width` or just increase `height` till you reach your desired form for mobile devices